# T-SQL Aggregate function subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I get the following error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

With this code:

```
SELECT 
    loc.Location
    ,COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN hr.SAC in (SELECT [SAC] FROM dbo.[Titles] WHERE [title] = 'XYZ')
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS XYZ_Trainee_Count
    ,COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN hr.SAC in (SELECT [SAC] FROM dbo.[Titles] WHERE [title] = 'ABC')
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS ABC_Trainee_Count

FROM
    dbo.n_HRODS hr INNER JOIN dbo.Locations loc
        ON loc.LocationID = hr.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmpData dat
        ON dat.EmpID = hr.EmpID

WHERE dat.Trainee = 1

GROUP BY loc.Location
```

dbo.[Titles] is a view that combines two columns from two other tables. I'm basically doing it this way because the programmer before me did something like this:

```
,COUNT(CASE 
    WHEN SAC in ( lists about 30 items)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE NULL 
    END)
```

Obviously, I don't want to list 30 items in that case statement... and when those items change for whatever reason in 3 years, then who's going to remember to go back in this code and updated those items? Nobody...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of extra `LEFT OUTER JOINs` to that `title` table:

```
SELECT 
    loc.Location
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN titles1.[SAC] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS XYZ_Trainee_Count
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN titles2.[SAC] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ABC_Trainee_Count

FROM
    dbo.n_HRODS hr INNER JOIN dbo.Locations loc
        ON loc.LocationID = hr.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmpData dat
        ON dat.EmpID = hr.EmpID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Titles] titles1
        ON titles1.[title]='XYZ' AND
            hr.SAC = titles1.[SAC]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Titles] titles2
        ON titles2.[title]='ABC' AND
            hr.sac = titles2.[SAC]    
WHERE dat.Trainee = 1    
GROUP BY loc.Location
```

Alternatively, if you are really married to those subqueries in your SELECT statement because the actual query is a big nightmare and the thought of monkeying with the joins is enough to make you faint, then you can just remove the aggregation from this query and shove it all into a subquery before aggregation:

```
SELECT location, count(XYZ_Trainee) AS XYZ_Trainee_Count, count(ABC_Trainee) as ABC_Trainee
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        loc.Location
        ,CASE 
            WHEN hr.SAC in (SELECT [SAC] FROM dbo.[Titles] WHERE [title] = 'XYZ')
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
            END AS XYZ_Trainee
        ,CASE 
            WHEN hr.SAC in (SELECT [SAC] FROM dbo.[Titles] WHERE [title] = 'ABC')
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
            END AS ABC_Trainee

    FROM
        dbo.n_HRODS hr INNER JOIN dbo.Locations loc
            ON loc.LocationID = hr.LocationID
        INNER JOIN dbo.EmpData dat
            ON dat.EmpID = hr.EmpID

    WHERE dat.Trainee = 1
) sub
GROUP BY location
```

I would aim for the first solution though since it's going to be easier to maintain and probably get a better execution path from your RDBMS and run quicker as a result. Although... that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to JNevill first answer. But if you join with title once, you can check and count for any number of title you want.

```
SELECT 
    loc.Location
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN t.[title] = 'XYZ' THEN 1 END) AS XYZ_Trainee_Count
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN t.[title] = 'ABC' THEN 1 END) AS ABC_Trainee_Count

FROM
    dbo.[n_HRODS] hr 
INNER JOIN dbo.[Locations] loc
        ON loc.LocationID = hr.LocationID
INNER JOIN dbo.[EmpData] dat
        ON dat.EmpID = hr.EmpID
INNER JOIN dbo.[Titles] t
        ON  hr.SAC = t.[SAC]    
WHERE dat.Trainee = 1

GROUP BY loc.Location
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for the info!